# Android Databinding: include forces <layout> tag?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, include, android-databinding

I'm currently struggling with `<include>` of layouts and the obligatory `<layout>`  tag for those.

I have a library which defines a layout of the Toolbar which should be used by other artifacts, regardless if they are using Databinding or not.

For the Databinding to work, the layout of the Toolbar needs to be wrapped inside a `<layout>` Tag.

Therefore I created two different includes of the Toolbar Layout.

include_toolbar.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    .../>
```

I tried to reuse the defined Toolbar and wrap it with layout tags like this

include_toolbar_binding.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        layout="@layout/include_toolbar"/>
</layout>
```

But that's not working, as this include needs to be wrapped again, right?

Is there any solution which does not require to define the Toolbar again in the (wrapped) binding include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't support include tags as the root. I can't remember whether or not data binding supports merge tags with include flags in the root, but I don't think so. You could try it and see. If they aren't supported, it is only data binding because Android normally does support it.

You can use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android=...>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    .../>
</layout>
```

for your toolbar. You can then choose to load it with the normal data binding loader:

```
IncludeLoaderBinding binding = IncludeLoaderBinding.inflate(inflater, ...);
```

or you can use non-data binding inflation:

```
View included = inflater.inflate(...);
```

Android Data Binding will properly strip the layout file so that it can be used without data binding. You may see some problems if you use string tags as they are replaced and any binding expression will be stripped. If you're using a plain layout like you mentioned, you won't have any trouble including it from both a data binding layout file and a non-data binding layout file.

-- edit --

Based on the comments I understand that one application doesn't have data binding enabled and this won't be supported. If you're looking to get field access to the Toolbar through data binding and support non-data binding projects, this combined layout won't work. If you don't need field access to the toolbar, you can just include a non-data binding layout file from a data binding layout file.

Comment: using the `<merge>` doesn't work.
Including the `<layout>` tag does not work, as I want to include the layout in the xml file and not inflating it via code.

Comment: You can include it in another layout also.

Comment: i'm defining this layout in a library which is used by apps that may **or may not** use databinding. if they don't i cannot wrap it with the `<layout>` tag.

Comment: Yes, you can wrap a layout that is included in both data binding and non-data binding layouts with <layout>.

Comment: if i try to include the toolbar wrapped in the `<layout>` tag in an app that has not enabled databinding in the `build.gradle` i get a runtime error on inflation: `ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.layout" on path: DexPathList`

Comment: Ah, I see. Data binding is not *enabled*. You're right -- if it isn't enabled then it won't work. It will work if it is enabled, but not used (normal layout including a data binding layout)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `<merge>`.

your toolbar.xml would look like this:

```
<merge>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        .../>
</merge>
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 0):

conclusion: it's not possible to use `<include>` as the root tag. (also not if the parent is `<merge>`).
therefore i need to define the Toolbar in both layouts separately.